# Issue with iterating through list of callable

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop, callable-statement

I am having an issue with iterating over a list of callables in python. The callables are supposed to be called on a generator of strings. The current behaviour is that the last callable in the list is called as many times as there are callables in the list. My current code:

```
for m in list_of_callables:
    strings = (m(s) for s in strings)
```

In the above code strings is initially of type 'Generator'. I have also tried the following:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_callables)):
    strings = (list__of_callables[i](s) for s in strings)
```

This has not worked either, but when I don't loop over the callables and simply call them it works just fine:

```
strings = (list_of_callables[0](s) for s in strings)
strings = (list_of_callables[1](s) for s in strings)
```

This seems strange to me as the above should be equivalent to the for loop.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions :).

Comment: This sounds like an episode of [late binding closures](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Comment: do you know what `generator` means? I think you want to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: What is the expected behavior here? I'm confused by your reuse of the  indentifier `strings` both inside and outside the generator. That makes it very hard to understand the reasoning behind your code.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yup, it sure was. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: @HåkenLid The expected behaviour was to modify the strings by using the callback functions (ie. append stuff to them, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings = (m(s) for s in strings)
```

This doesn't actually call your callable. It creates a generator expression that will call `m` later, *using whatever `m` happens to be later*.

After the loop, `m` is the final callable. When you try to retrieve an element from `strings`, all those nested genexps look up `m` to compute a value, and they all find the last callable.

You could fix this by using `itertools.imap` instead of a genexp:

```
strings = itertools.imap(m, strings)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :)